# I want to convert 160-bit to integer

Tags: sha

I am using `SHA1` so i want to convert the output of this `SHA1` to integer

Comment: Can you better explain your question?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. SHA1 outputs a 160-bit integer. Do you want to convert it to the string representation of an integer, perhaps?

Comment: I'd at least give the OP an hour or two to clarify the question prior to closing it.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
echo preg_replace("/[^0-9]/i", "", sha1("apikot"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could represent 160 bits in 5 long ints.  That could be an array of 5 long ints, or you could have it be an array of 10 short ints.  Are you trying to make it easier to handle than a string of characters/bits?

Answer (score 0):

This will convert the sha1sum of /tmp/a to a decimal integer:

```
$ (echo ibase=16; (cat /tmp/a | sha1sum | tr a-z A-Z | sed s/-// )) | bc
```

Comment: Useless use of cat :-) -- `sha1sum < /tmp/a | ...`