# SHA1 - Convert the string to integer

Tags: shell, type-conversion, sha1

I know that is a duplicate question from here : [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699451/i-want-to-convert-160-bit-to-integer)

I tried to do a little more research into if its possible or no at-all.
and I see that it is possible.

The only thing I want to get is what is the `function` that I need to use to `convert a string to an integer` in shell scripting. SHA1 is a 160bit long integer.

Motivation behind doing it on shell scripting : trying to learning it.

For example I get the `sha1` of a file by storing it in a variable like this

```
store=`sha1 $blah | cut -d  ' ' -f 1`
```

it gives me the hash . But what if I want to convert it to integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Impossible. For the shell, everything is a string. If you leave POSIX, and declare shell variables as having integer type, the width of the integer is usually that of the underlying C library, i.e. 32 or 64 bit. SHA1 hashes with 160bits don't fit.
However, there are the `bc` and `dc` utilities, which allow arbitrary precision arithmetic.
If you just want to convert the hex string to a decimal number, use this:

```
$ bc << EOF
obase=10
ibase=16
DA19BAC0F234635B6DE9362369DA07A6A4162865
1245133775210903227706347819370390008085985241189
EOF
```

Note that you MUST USE CAPITAL HEX DIGITS, because `bc` won't recognize a-f.

Comment: May I ask what is the arbitrary precision probability that way?

Comment: Arbitrary precision means they can do arithmetic with numbers of any length, like 160 digit hex numbers.